# class.forName equivalent in c# without creating an instance

Tags: c#, static-methods

I want to dynamically access classes in c# in the way like Java `class.forName()`. I have only found things like [Class.forName() equivalent in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979484/class-forname-equivalent-in-net) but I don't want to create instances.

In detail: I have got a simple text file containing a list of classes. I read them using `file.ReadLine()` (so I have got all class names as strings) and then I want to execute the same static method on each class: `class1.method(); class2.method;` and so on. The classes all exist and I need to access them. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried the `static` keyword? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static

Comment: Try using System.Reflection. You may have to get hold of MethodInfo by loading the Assembly and executing GetMethod passing in Flags to retrieve the required method and execute it.

Comment: @Pikoh _I want to execute the same static method on each class_

Comment: @juharr didn't see it, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# doesn't support static interfaces (or static members in interfaces), so unless you want to use factory classes (the usual approach), you'll need to use reflection to invoke the static method directly.

```
void Main()
{

  Console.WriteLine(Type.GetType("A").GetMethod("Hi").Invoke(null, new object[] {}));
}

class A
{
  public static string Hi() { return "Hi!"; }
}
```

You might want to use a fully-qualified name for the type to make this work really well. Using just the name of the type is tricky, especially when you're trying to invoke types from other assemblies (which you probably are, otherwise there'd be no reason to use reflection - just use a dictionary of delegates or whatever).

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be what I need. The problem is that there is always a NullReferenceException during execution although I am sure that the class (which you called "A") exists. It also happens on such simple snippets like `Console.WriteLine(Type.GetType("A").ToString())` so I think the problem is in the `getType()` method. The additional Information says "The object reference was not set on an object instance". I don't understand that because I don't need/ don't want an instance (and my method is static!)

Comment: @user5325622 You do not need an instance of your type, but you do need the `Type` instance of the type - `GetType` returns null when the type isn't found. That's why I mentioned you may need to use a more qualified name than just `A` - a fully or assembly-qualified name. You can see what the assembly qualified name of the type is by using `typeof(A).AssemblyQualifiedName`. If you just put my sample code in your `Program` class, `A` would be a nested class and inside a namespace, so you'd need at least something like `TestApp.Program+A` or so.

Comment: Thanks. That works well for hard coded classnames. But what about the specific situation described above: "I have got a simple text file containing a list of classes (so I have got all class names as strings)"? I can't explicitly determine the type of a class when I have only got the classname as a string and not the class itself.

Comment: @user5325622 And now take the assembly qualified name, and use *that* in your text file. Just the name of the type isn't enough to locate the correct assembly, namespace etc.

Comment: Yes, of course :)
Thank you very much, now everything works well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Reflection to load the Assembly into memory and then drill down to the type followed by getting the required method and invoke.

Refer to the documentation

[GetMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05eey4y9(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you have names of your desired `Type` then you can use [`Type.GetType(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1(v=vs.110).aspx) method.
Example if you have a class like this :

```
namespace MeProgram.BusinessLogic
{
    public class MeObject {}
}
```

Full class name of that object should be `"MeProgram.BusinessLogic.MeObject"`.

Now you can use that name inside of `Type.GetType(string)` method like such :

```
string className = "MeProgram.BusinessLogic.MeObject";
Type classType = Type.GetType(className);
```